# jquery get value of grouped radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, clone, tablerow

How do I get the value of a  radio button group when the add button is clicked?

Below is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/RBYzm/

Whenever I add a row to the other table no matter which radio button I select it does not showup as selected in the table that I am adding rows to.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not setting the values of row that is added to the one from which you want to add.. You are just creating the elements but not copying over the values from the main table..

Why don't you just use `.clone()` instead..

**EDIT**

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RBYzm/5/)

I have made some changes in the code.. Changed the id's where there were duplicates.. Also accessing the values of the current row and copying it over to the newly added row..

Comment: because even with .clone I can't get the value of the radio button to show up in the row that I add

Comment: You are not adding the values of the row to be added to the newly added row.. Also you need to make sure the vID's are unique on the page

Comment: it still gets the value for everyhting except for the radio button :(